# jQuery - extract specific string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a hidden form element where I am storing a duplicate copy of a DIV that I have displayed on my page. I am looking to try and extract a piece of text from the entire string, but have not been able to find the correct code.

Seeing as though this string is stored within hidden form element, I can easily get it back out using .val() - my issue arises when I try to iterate through the string to the second label and simply extract the text within. My intended output that I am trying to achieve is "**6:00 AM - 6:00 PM (Description)**". The rest of the string can be completely stripped away.

The string returned from the hidden form element is:

```
<div class="form-group" style="display: block;" id="tab4_patrolmondaycontainer">
<label class="control-label col-md-3" style="font-weight:bold;">Monday:</label>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <p class="form-control-static" id="tab4_patrolmonday">
        <div id="88340032">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3" style="font-weight:bold;">
                <a style="color:#000000;" href="javascript:RemoveElement('88340032', 'D', '')"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;Patrol Window: 
            </label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label class="control-label">6:00 AM - 6:00 PM (Description)</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe `$(".form-group label:eq(2)").html()` ?

Comment: If you have the same information in an actual element in the DOM – then why would you want to use string matching to get it …? That makes no sense at all.

Comment: Is that value an actual string? or it's a full copy of all the elements?

Comment: @FGhilardi - This method worked perfectly, thanks so much!!! Here is another scenario, the code I provided above could potentially appear more than once. How would I extract the string value from each set?? Basically, the user is capturing shifts, so the code above could be repeated per shift with different values, i.e. 6:00 AM - 6:00 PM (Description) and 6:00 PM - 8:00 PM (Description) and 8:00 AM - 10:00 PM (Description).... Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!!! –

Answer (score 0):

jQuery(".form-group .form-control-static .col-md-4 .control-label").html() should give you back the string you want.

However if the above html you mentioned is in a string format, you can convert it into DOM element and then use the above query to get the desired output.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BL5qn/   if you want to mess with it as an actual string but really try and use it as DOM elements.

Comment: Understood. How would I convert it to a DOM element?? The code for manipulating the string works 100% - thank you. But just for curiosity sake, I would be interested to see the other way working too.

Comment: @FGhilardi - This method worked perfectly, thanks so much!!! Here is another scenario, the code I provided above could potentially appear more than once. How would I extract the string value from each set?? Basically, the user is capturing shifts, so the code above could be repeated per shift with different values, i.e. 6:00 AM - 6:00 PM (Description) and 6:00 PM - 8:00 PM (Description) and 8:00 AM - 10:00 PM (Description).... Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

You also could get the string out with a regular expression if it's alway in a similar format, the expression would be something like:

```
[0-9]{0,2}:[0-9]{0,2} [APM]{2} \- [0-9]{0,2}:[0-9]{0,2} [APM]{2} \([A-Za-z0-1]*\)
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/m6kxj/
BTW thx FGhilardi for the string^^

But like some people already have mentioned why not use the actual DOM elements they are already there so where would be the problem.
And just but curios how did you get the html into the input?